# Expresión regular para calculadora Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

Estoy intentando hacer varias expresiones regulares para una calculadora básica. El **string** estará compuestos por los caracteres `+ - * /` y números enteros, siguiendo la siguiente estructura.

`n1 + n2 – n3 * n4 / n5 …`

El objetivo es que me permita introducir solo operaciones de `+ -` y cifras de 2 dígitos en el grado 1 y en los demás que me permita las 4 operaciones básicas `+ - * /` y cifras de más dígitos.

---

**Código**

```
private void TextBoxOperation_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var text = TextBoxOperation.Text + e.Text;

    if (SelectedGrade == 1)
    {
        var regexItem = new Regex(@"[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}[-+ ]{0,2}");
        e.Handled = !regexItem.IsMatch(text);
    }
    else if (SelectedGrade == 2)
    {
        var regexItem = new Regex(@"[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[-+*\/ ]{0,2}");
        e.Handled = !regexItem.IsMatch(text);
    }
    //...
}
```

---

**1er grado**

```
  Entrada   | Salida 
n + n       | true
n - n       | true
n * n       | false
n / n       | false
nn + n - n  | true
n + nn - n  | true
n + n - nn  | true
nnn + n - n | false
nnnn + n - n| false
```

**2do grado**

```
  Entrada   | Salida 
n + n       | true
n - n       | true
n * n       | true
n / n       | true
nn + n - n  | true
n + nn - n  | true
n + n - nn  | true
nnn + n - n | true
nnnn + n - n| false
```

---

**Actualización**

En caso de utilizar `[0-9*+-\/ ]` siempre me retorna **true**. El problema es que me permite escribir múltiples caracteres `++, +-, ...`, múltiples espacios y no tengo control en la cantidad de cifras. También me he fijado que **e.Text** solo me retorna el ultimo **char**.

---

**Recompensa**

Si aparte de lo anterior, también permite espacios y paréntesis.

```
    Entrada     | Salida 
)               | false
(               | true
(+              | false
( +             | false
()              | false
( n             | true
( n +           | true
(n+n)           | true
( n + n )       | true
nn + (n – n)    | true
(n + nn) – n    | true
(n + n) – nn))  | false
((n + n) – nn)) | true
```

Espero, que alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: El primer número siempre tiene que ser de mínimo dos dígitos? O `1 + 1 + 1` podría ser válido en algún caso?

Comment: Actualmente estoy usando este `[ ]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}[-+*\/ ]{0,2}` el problema de este es que me permite hasta 2 caracteres. `++, *-, ...`

Comment: Con el enunciado no queda claro qué valores puede adoptar el primer número. ¿Siempre tiene que ser de mínimo dos dígitos? O por el contrario, `1 + 1 + 1` podría ser válido en algún caso.

Comment: como puedes ver estoy utilizando `PreviewTextInput` el regex comprobara en cada input del teclado. minimo 1 digito para todos los grados, el maximo es lo que va a variar segun el grado. 1ro 2 digitos, 2do 3 digitos, 3ro 5 digitos, etc...

Comment: Donde esta @mariano cuando se lo necesita.. :/

Comment: Qué tal esta 1er grado: https://regex101.com/r/8JYSsk/2 y esta pra 2do grado: https://regex101.com/r/8JYSsk/4    (nota: permito 'n' para verlo más fácil, las expresiones regulares final serían diferentes. Es simplemente para ver si serviría)

Comment: Me retorna true despues de introducir la primera operación `n + n`. no me reconoce en caso de escribir `n` o `n +`. Recuerda que el texbox empieza en blanco.

Comment: Ok!, qué tal esta para las de primer grado? https://regex101.com/r/8JYSsk/5

Comment: Si se puede utilizar. Un Pluss seria si aceptara `( )` parentesis y espacios.

Comment: Tiene que ser usando regex o se admiten otras soluciones?

Comment: ¿Puede permitir el signo de resta (`-`), o suma al principio? Ejemplo: `-20+10`. En ese caso, hacer `(-` debería dar `true` ya que la predicción es `(-20`, pero se aclara que `(+` es `false`. ¿Debería ser así? ¿Consideras que está mal que una calculadora acepte múltiples espacios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solución con expresiones regulares

Prueba con la siguiente expresión regular para el caso del **primer** grado. Permite paréntesis balanceados y espacios:

`^(?!.*\([ \t]*\))(?!.*[+-][ \t]*[+-])(?!.*\([ \t]*[+-])(?!.*[+-][ \t]*\))(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*(?:(?:(?'open'\()(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*)+(?:(?'-open'\)?)(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*)+)*\s*$`

Tienes una demo [aquí](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5c%28%5b+%5ct%5d*%5c%29%29%28%3f!.*%5b%2b-%5d%5b+%5ct%5d*%5b%2b-%5d%29%28%3f!.*%5c%28%5b+%5ct%5d*%5b%2b-%5d%29%28%3f!.*%5b%2b-%5d%5b+%5ct%5d*%5c%29%29%28%3f%3a%5b%2b-%5d%7c%5cb%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5cb%7c%5b+%5ct%5d%29*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%28%3f%27open%27%5c%28%29%28%3f%3a%5b%2b-%5d%7c%5cb%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5cb%7c%5b+%5ct%5d%29*%29%2b%28%3f%3a%28%3f%27-open%27%5c%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5b%2b-%5d%7c%5cb%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5cb%7c%5b+%5ct%5d%29*%29%2b%29*%5cs*%24&i=Debe+encontrar%3a%0d%0a1+%2b+1+%2b11%0d%0a%281+%2b++11%29-1%0d%0a1%2b%28%0d%0a%28%0d%0a%28+1%0d%0a%281+%2b%0d%0a%281+%2b+1++%29%0d%0a%281+%2b+1%29%0d%0a11++%2b%281++-1%29%0d%0a%281%2b+11%29+-+1%0d%0a%28%28%281+%2b+1%29+%2b+%281-1%29+%2b+%281%2b%282%2b3%29%29+-+1%29%29%0d%0a%28%28%281+%2b+1%29+%2b+%281-1%29+%2b+%281%2b%282%2b3%29%29+-%0d%0a%28%281%29%2b1%2b%281%29%29%0d%0a%281%29%0d%0a%0d%0aFallos%3a%0d%0aErrores+varios%3a%0d%0a%28%2b%0d%0a%28+%2b%0d%0a%28+%29%0d%0a%2811+%2b+%29%0d%0a%29%0d%0a%28%29%0d%0a%0d%0aTienen+demasiados+par%c3%a9ntesis+de+cierre%3a%0d%0a%281%2b1%29-11%29%29%0d%0a%28%281%2b1%29-11%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0aNo+es+primer+grado%3a%0d%0a%28111%2b1%29%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m).

---

Para el caso de segundo grado, puedes utilizar esta otra:

`^(?!.*\([ \t]*\))(?!.*[+/*-][ \t]*[+/*-])(?!.*\([ \t]*[+/*-])(?!.*[+/*-][ \t]*\))(?:[+/*-]|\b\d{1,3}\b|[ \t])*(?:(?:(?'open'\()(?:[+/*-]|\b\d{1,3}\b|[ \t])*)+(?:(?'-open'\)?)(?:[+/*-]|\b\d{1,3}\b|[ \t])*)+)*\s*$`

---

### Explicación:

Ambas están basadas en la funcionalidad de las expresiones regulares de .NET de "grupos balanceados". Recomiendo [esta lectura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) sobre grupos balanceados. Donde se explicarán mucho mejor de lo que pueda hacerlo yo aquí.

En esa misma página se propone una expresión regular para buscar paréntesis balanceados con cualquier caracter (que no sea paréntesis) entre medias.

La expresión es esta: `^[^()]*(?>(?>(?'open'\()[^()]*)+(?>(?'-open'\))[^()]*)+)+(?(open)(?!))$`

Aquí haremos algún cambio. Primeramente haremos el cierre de paréntesis opcional, ya que nuestro texto puede ser válido a medida que se escribe. Además, borraremos [el condicional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), que aborta (mediante un [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) que siempre falla) en caso de encontrar más paréntesis abiertos que cerrados.

Además, como ahora el cierre del paréntesis es opcional, cambiaremos los [grupos atómicos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) por grupos normales, ya que necesitaremos poder hacer backtracking.

Así pues, tras los cambios queda algo así:

`^[^()]*(?:(?:(?'open'\()[^()]*)+(?:(?'-open'\)?)[^()]*)+)+$`

Pero hay que seguir con los cambios:

En lugar de permitir cualquier cosa entre los paréntesis, lo que haremos será permitir una de estas opciones:

1. Una operación `[+-]`
2. Blancos (tabulador o espacio) `[\t ]`
3. Un número de uno a dos `\b\d{1,2}\b`

Todo eso se podrá repetir de 0 a más veces, así que entre los paréntesis podemos obtener cosas como `1+1+1-2`, pero también cosas incorrectas como `+++++`. Pero esto lo solucionaremos más adelante.

De momento la expresión regular queda así:

`^(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*(?:(?:(?'open'\()(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*)+(?:(?'-open'\)?)(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*)+)*$`

Finalmente para evitar el posible contenido incorrecto comentado anteriormente, añadiremos al principio de la expresión regular validaciones hechas con lookaheads. Iremos excluyendo todos los casos incorrectos que se puedan dar. Como:

1. **Evitar paréntesis vacíos "()":** `(?!.*\([ \t]*\))`
2. **Evitar dos o más operaciones seguidas "++":** `(?!.*[+-][ \t]*[+-])`
3. **Evitar paréntesis abierto y luego operación:** `(?!.*\([ \t]*[+-])`
4. **Evitar operación seguido de paréntesis cerrado:** `(?!.*[+-][ \t]*\))`

Así conseguimos la expresión regular final resultante:

`^(?!.*\([ \t]*\))(?!.*[+-][ \t]*[+-])(?!.*\([ \t]*[+-])(?!.*[+-][ \t]*\))(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*(?:(?:(?'open'\()(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*)+(?:(?'-open'\)?)(?:[+-]|\b\d{1,2}\b|[ \t])*)+)*\s*$`

Para la segunda expresión regular, cambiamos todos los `[+-]` por `[+/*-]` para permitir así el resto de operaciones. También cambiaremos los `\b{1,2}\b` por `\b{1,3}\b` para permitir números de hasta tres dígitos.

Comment: Gracias @Julio.

Comment: de nada @JesseR.Jose, si te sirvió recuerda a marcar la respuesta como aceptada, la recompensa caduca mañana :)